# R studio lp solve hanging, how to fix

Tags: r

I am using lp solve in r to solve an optimization problem, but sometimes the function runs into an issue and hangs. Rstudio has the red stop-sign logo that I can click to terminate the program, however for some reason the stop-sign does not break this particular error.

Other than clicking the stop sign, is there any way to terminate the console from running when a function gets stuck? Something that I can do automatically (i.e. if the console is stuck hanging for 10+ seconds, then terminate) would be great.

thanks!

Comment: Is the problem too hard to be solved in 10 seconds ?

Comment: when the function doesn't get hung up, it returns a solution in <1 second

Answer (score 0):

If the problem is, that the optimization is too complex, you can use the function lp.control. Where:

```
lp.control( "Name of optimization problem", timeout= "number of seconds before termination")
```

lp.solver will look for all possible answers, so stopping it will yield the best answer found during the timeframe.